# How to Setup Recurring Payments

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, recurring-billing

How can i integrate recurring payment in paypal using codeigniter platform.Can anybody share some good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <form id="fPayPal" method="post" name="paypal_form" action="<?= $paypal_url ?>" style="display: none">
<!-- PayPal Configuration --> 
<input type="text" name="business" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($settings_list['PayPalEmail']->Value) ?>"> <br />
<?php if($recurring) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="a3" value="<?= $camp_member_info->Total ?>"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="p3" value="1"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="t3" value="M"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="src" value="1"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="srt" value="<?= $month_count ?>"><br/>
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <br />
<?php } ?>

<input type="text" name="custom" value="<?= $camp_member_info->ID ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="shopping_url" value="<?= esc_url(get_permalink()) ?>" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="return" value="<?= esc_url($this->get_front_url('paypal-thankyou', $location_id, $price_id)) ?>" /><br />
<br />
<input type="text" name="rm" value="2"><br />
<input type="text" name="currency_code" value="USD"><br />
<input type="text" name="lc" value="US"><br />
<input type="text" name="bn" value="toolkit-php"><br />
<input type="text" name="cbt" value="Continue"><br /><br />

<!-- Payment Page Information --> 
<input type="text" name="no_shipping" value=""><br />
<input type="text" name="no_note" value="1"><br />
<input type="text" name="cn" value="Comments"> <br />
<input type="text" name="cs" value=""><br /><br />

<!-- Product Information --> 
<input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($price->Name) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($camp_member_info->Price) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /><br />
<?php if($coupon !== null) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="discount_amount" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($camp_member_info->Discount) ?>" /><br />
<?php } ?>

<br />

<!-- Customer Information --> 
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->Email) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->FirstName) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->LastName) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="address1" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->Address1) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="address2" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->Address2) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="state" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->State) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->City) ?>" /><br />
<input type="text" name="zip" value="<?= $this->prepareToDisaplay($member->Zip) ?>" /><br /><br />



<input type="submit" value="PP" /><br />
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
a3 = amount of ONE billing period
t3 = time period (M - month, D - day, etc...)
p3 = number of time periods in billing period
src = 1 (1 - for recuring payments)
srt = number of billing periods

Description: a3 dollars, each p3 t3, for srt installments
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, what are the initial steps i have to take for implement this?i have a sandbox account a buyer and business account.I have implemented everything for normal paypal integration.What are the changes and updation to be done for implementing recurrent? can i get the back end also for the post ?

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/recurring-payment-processing                                   https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/subscription-button

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/signin/?returnUri=http%3A%2F%2Furi.paypal.com%2FWeb%2FWeb%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr%3Fvia%3Dul&state=%3fcmd%3d_web-tools%26CALL_FORM_UPDATE%3dfalse%26factory_type%3dbuynow%26fli%3dtrue%26fli%3dtrue

Comment: thank you so much for the help, let me check and reply back

Comment: hi can i get a help, am getting an error while trying to implement automatic billing like "Sorry, this feature is not available at this time." How can i solve this

Comment: yes correct, i have noticed that if we have sandbox pro account then we can create automatic billing button.Do we need to upgrade the business account?